# ExportRenderer could not be found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a custom page renderer in Xamarin and I am having some issues with the references.  Namely, I get "could not be found" on ExportRenderer as well as PageRenderer.  Here is my code:

```html
using CoreAnimation;
using CoreGraphics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Utilities.GradientRenderer;
using Utilities.GradientRenderer.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(GradientContentPage), typeof(GradientContentPageRenderer))]
namespace Utilities.GradientRenderer.iOS
{
    public class GradientContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e) 
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null) // perform initial setup
            {
                var page = e.NewElement as GradientContentPage;
                var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
                gradientLayer.Frame = View.Bounds;
                gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] { page.StartColor.ToCGColor(), page.EndColor.ToCGColor() };
                View.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin.Forms version 2.3.3.168

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `using` based upon the `Xamarin.Forms` platform that you  are writing the renderer for, i.e.

Android:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
```

iOS:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and I am getting "iOS does not exist in the namespace XamarinForms.Platform"  It seems to me that I am missing an assembly reference, but I cannot figure out which one.

Comment: @dpdragnev Assuming that this is a `Xamarin.iOS` project, all you should have to do is add the `Xamarin.Forms` package and that in turn will auto add references to `Xamarin.Forms.Core`, `Xamarin.Forms.Platform' and `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS` within your `.csproj`

Comment: This is actually a PCL project.  I have the iOS project in the solution, but I am working in the Portable library project.

Comment: @dpdragnev Platform dependent renderers have to be created in a platform dependent library, a PCL library can not have iOS or Android references. In the PCL library you can define the renderer interface that each platform dependent library can than implement.

Comment: Thank you @SushiHangover.  I just realized that.  I moved the class to the iOS project and everything worked as expected.